# Reading specific column from file when last few rows are not equivalent in python

Tags: python, split, readfile

I have a problem during the reading of a text file in python. Basically what I need is to get the 4th column in a list.

With this small function I achieve it without any great issues:

```
def load_file(filename):


    f = open(filename, 'r')

   # skip the first useless row
   line = list(f.readlines()[1:])

   total_sp = []


    for i in line:
        t = i.strip().split()
        total_sp.append(int(t[4]))

    return total_sp
```

but now I have to manage files, that in the last row(s) have any random number that don't respect the text format. An example of the **not** working text file is:

```
#generated file
well10_1         3        18         6         1         2  -0.01158   0.01842       142
well5_1         1        14         6         1         2  0.009474   0.01842       141
well4_1         1        13         4         1         2  -0.01842  -0.03737       125
well7_1         3        10         1         1         2 -0.002632  0.009005       101
well3_1         1        10         9         1         2  -0.03579  -0.06368       157
well8_1         3        10        10         1         2  -0.06895   -0.1021       158
well9_1         3        10        18         1         2   0.03053   0.02158       176
well2_1         1         4         4         1         2  -0.03737  -0.03737       128
well6_1         3         4         5         1         2  -0.07053   -0.1421       127
well1_1        -2         3         1         1         2  0.006663  -0.02415       128
         1    0.9259
         2   0.07407
```

where `1    0.9259` and `2   0.07407` have to be dumped.

In fact, using the function of above with this text file, I get the following error because of the 2 additional last rows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpqi8Ktw.py", line 21, in load_obh
    total_sp.append(int(t[4]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I get rid of the last lines in the `line` variable?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this, one such way can be to handle the `indexError` by surrounding the erroneous code by `try and except`, something like this :

```
try :
    total_sp.append(int(t[4]))
except IndexError : 
    pass
```

This will only append to the `total_sp` when index exits otherwise not. Also, this will handle whenever you do not have the data present corresponding to that particular index.

Alternatively, if you are interested in removing just the last two rows (elements), you can use the [slice operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) such as by replacing `line = list(f.readlines()[1:])` with `line = f.readlines()[1:-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines` already returns a list. Just as you provide a start index to slice from, you can specify "2 before the end" using negative indexing as below:

```
line = f.readlines()[1:-2]
```

Should do the trick.

EDIT: To handle an arbitrary number of lines at the end:

```
def load_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')

    # skip the first useless row
    line = f.readlines()[1:]

    total_sp = []
    for i in line:
        t = i.strip().split()
        # check if enough columns were found
        if len(t) >= 5:
            total_sp.append(int(t[4]))

    return total_sp
```

Comment: thanks.. maybe I was not clear enough in my question sorry :( the specific file yes, has the 2 rows at the end, while I can get other files that could have many other lines...

Comment: I see. Are the last n lines always going to have just the 2 columns? Or could the type of data in those last lines change?

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a "your case-specific" solution:

```
for i in line:
    if not i.startswith(' '):
        t = i.strip().split()
        total_sp.append(int(t[4]))
```

Comment: sorry.. not always the file will start with `well`.. my fault in not explaining it

Comment: How about now? You already have good answers, this is just for fun :)